# Phpmailer send attachments as plain text

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

When I use phpmailer to send four pdf attachments, one is sent as pdf and three of them as plain text. Like this is sent only on macbook app mail. On gamil sent all 4 attachments well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79OKU.jpg)

enter code here

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = '***************';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '***************';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('ebytyebyty@gmail.com', 'ebyty dokumenty');


        // Add a recipient;
        $mail->addAddress('drakxy998@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress($email);


        // Attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('Objednávka'.$id_fakt.'.pdf', $name = 'Objednávka_'.$id_fakt.'.pdf',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');         // Add attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('Plnomocenstvo.pdf', $name = 'Plnomocenstvo.pdf',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');    // Optional name
        $mail->addAttachment('Súhlassospracúvanímosobnýchúdajov.pdf', $name = 'Súhlas_so_spracúvaním_osobných_údajov.pdf',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
        $mail->addAttachment('Vyhlásenieomajetku.pdf', $name = 'Vyhlásenie_o_majetku.pdf',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');


        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'ebyty dokumenty';


        $mail->Body = 'text';

        $mail->AltBody = 'ebyty dokumenty';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear and easier to read. As it is now people may have to guess what your question is.

Comment: How is the Gmail observation more relevant than looking at the raw mail / MIME structure?